# Remover tag na geração de XML com XStream

Tags: java

Como que podemos remover a tag `<list>` gerada automaticamente no `XStream` durante o processo de serialização? Tenho três classes para este cenário: uma para teste e duas para alimentar dados que serão gerados no xml.

Classe de teste:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<Object> balancos = new ArrayList<Object>();
XStreamBalancoTester tester = new XStreamBalancoTester();

//Serialização
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver()); //Stax imprime em linha unica com cabeçalho
xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
xstream.alias("balanco", Balanco.class);
xstream.alias("operacao", Operacao.class);      
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);  
balancos = tester.getBalancos(5);
String xml = xstream.toXML(balancos);
System.out.println(xml);
```

XML Gerado:

```
<list>
<balanco>
<id >5< /id>
<compras>
<operacao>
<papel>ub22< /papel>
<valor>30.62< /valor>
<quantidade>150.0< /quantidade>
<data>2020-01-27 19:50:12.937 UTC< /data>
</operacao>
</compras>
</balanco>
</list>
```

Já tentei com `xstream.omitField(Name.class, “tag”)` e `xstream.addImplicitCollection(Name.class, “tag”)` mas não deram certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31047788/skip-a-tag-related-to-a-list-with-xstream), você pode utilizar a *annotation* `@XStreamImplicit` da seguinte maneira:

```
   @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="OrderLine")
   ArrayList<OrderLine> orderLines;
```

Ou utilizando o método `addImplicitCollection` conforme abaixo:

```
xstream.addImplicitCollection(Order.class, "orderLines", "OrderLine", OrderLine.class);
```